# java.util.Scanner; vs JOptionPane;

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

**Please I would like know How would I implement JOptionPane instead of import java.util.Scanner;
I also have 4 separate classes**
If i implement JOptionPane will it clean up the code I would also like to know any changes anyone would make.

**Employee.Class**

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
    public static int numEmployees = 0;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected char gender;
    protected int dependents;
    protected double annualSalary;
    private NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    public Benefit benefit;
    private static Scanner scan;

    public Employee() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        gender = 'U';
        dependents = 0;
        annualSalary = 40000;
        benefit = new Benefit();
        numEmployees++;
    }

    public Employee(String first, String last, char gen, int dep, Benefit benefit1) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.gender = gen;
        this.annualSalary = 40000;
        this.dependents = dep;
        this.benefit = benefit1;
        numEmployees++;
    }

    public double calculatePay1() {
        return annualSalary / 52;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("First Name: ").append(firstName).append("\n");
        sb.append("Last Name: ").append(lastName).append("\n");
        sb.append("Gender: ").append(gender).append("\n");
        sb.append("Dependents: ").append(dependents).append("\n");
        sb.append("Annual Salary: ").append(nf.format(getAnnualSalary())).append("\n");
        sb.append("Weekly Pay: ").append(nf.format(calculatePay1())).append("\n");
        sb.append(benefit.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public <Gender> void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public <Gender> char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setDependents(int dependents) {
        this.dependents = dependents;
    }

    public void setDependents(String dependents) {
        this.dependents = Integer.parseInt(dependents);
    }

    public int getDependents() {
        return dependents;
    }

    public void setAnnualSalary(double annualSalary) {
        this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
    }

    public void setAnnualSalary(String annualSalary) {
        this.annualSalary = Double.parseDouble(annualSalary);
    }

    public double getAnnualSalary() {
        return annualSalary;
    }


    public double calculatePay() {
        return annualSalary / 52;
    }   

    public double getAnnualSalary1() {
        return annualSalary;
    }

    public static void displayDivider(String outputTitle) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + outputTitle + " <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    }

    public static String getInput(String inputType) {
        System.out.println("Enter the " + inputType + ": ");
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.next();
        return input;
    }

    public static int getNumEmployees() {
        return numEmployees;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayDivider("New Employee Information");
        Benefit benefit = new Benefit();
        Employee employee = new Employee("George", "Anderson", 'M', 5, benefit);
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
        System.out.println("Total employees: " + getNumEmployees());
        displayDivider("Hourly Temp Employee Information");
        Hourly hourly = new Hourly("Mary", "Nola", 'F', 5, 14, 45, "temp");
        System.out.println(hourly.toString());
        System.out.println("Total employees: " + getNumEmployees());
        displayDivider("Hourly Full Time Employee Information");
        Hourly hourly1 = new Hourly("Mary", "Nola", 'F', 5, 18, 42, "full time");
        System.out.println(hourly1.toString());
        System.out.println("Total employees: " + getNumEmployees());
        displayDivider("Hourly Part Time Employee Information");
        Hourly hourly11 = new Hourly("Mary", "Nola", 'F', 5, 18, 20, "part time");
        System.out.println(hourly11.toString());
        System.out.println("Total employees: " + getNumEmployees());
        displayDivider("Salaried Revised Employee Information");
        Benefit benefit1 = new Benefit("None", 500, 3);
        Salaried salaried = new Salaried("Frank", "Lucus", 'M', 5, 150000, benefit1, 3);
        System.out.println(salaried.toString());
        System.out.println("Total employees: " + getNumEmployees());    
        displayDivider("Salaried Employee Information");
        Benefit benefit11 = new Benefit("None", 500, 3);
        Salaried salaried1 = new Salaried("Frank", "Lucus", 'M', 5, 100000, benefit11, 2);
        System.out.println(salaried1.toString());
        System.out.println("Total employees: " + getNumEmployees());
    }
}
```

**SALARIED.CLASS**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salaried extends Employee {

    private static final int MIN_MANAGEMENT_LEVEL = 0;
    private static final int MAX_MANAGEMENT_LEVEL = 3;
    private static final int BONUS_PERCENT = 10;
    private int managementLevel;
    private Scanner in;

    public Salaried() {
        super();
        Random rand = new Random();
        managementLevel = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        if (managementLevel == 0) {
            System.out.println("Not Valid");
        }
        //numEmployees++;
    }

    private boolean validManagementLevel(int level) {
        return (MIN_MANAGEMENT_LEVEL <= level && level <= MAX_MANAGEMENT_LEVEL);
    }

    public Salaried(String fname, String lname, char gen, int dep, 
        double sal, Benefit ben, int manLevel) 
    {
        super.firstName = fname;
        super.lastName = lname;
        super.gender = gen;
        super.dependents = dep;
        super.annualSalary = sal;
        super.benefit = ben;
        while (true) {
            if (!validManagementLevel(manLevel)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid management level, please enter 
                another management   level            value     in range [0,3]: ");
                manLevel = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            } else {
                managementLevel = manLevel;
                break;
            }
        }
        //numEmployees++;
    }

    public Salaried(double sal, int manLevel) {
        super.annualSalary = sal;
        while (true) {
            if (!validManagementLevel(manLevel)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid management level, please enter another 
                management level value   in range [0,3]: ");
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                manLevel = in.nextInt();
            } else {
                managementLevel = manLevel;
                break;
            }
        }
    //      numEmployees++;
    }

    @Override
    public double calculatePay() {
        double  percentage = managementLevel * BONUS_PERCENT;
        return (1 + percentage/100.0) * annualSalary / 52;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(super.toString());
        sb.append("Management Level: ").append(managementLevel).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**Hourly.Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Hourly extends Employee {
    private static final double MIN_WAGE = 10;
    private static final double MAX_WAGE = 75;
    private static final double MIN_HOURS = 0;
    private static final double MAX_HOURS = 50;
    private double wage;
    private double hours;
    private String category;
    private Scanner in;
    private Scanner in2;
    private Scanner in3;
    private Scanner in4;


    public Hourly() {
        super();
        this.wage = 20;
        this.hours= 30;
        this.category = "full time";
        annualSalary = wage * hours * 52;
    }

    public Hourly(double wage_, double hours_, String category_) {
        while (true) {
            if (!validWage(wage_)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid wage: ");
                in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                wage_ = in2.nextDouble();
            } else {
                this.wage = wage_;
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            if (!validHour(hours_)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid hours: ");
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                hours_ = in.nextDouble();
            } else {
                this.hours = hours_;
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            if (!validCategory(category_)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid category, please enter another category value: ");
                category_ = new Scanner(System.in).next();
            } else {
                this.category = category_;
                break;
            }
        }
        annualSalary = wage * hours * 52;
        //numEmployees++;
    }

    public Hourly(String fname, String lname, char gen, int dep, double wage_,double hours_, String  category_) {
        super.firstName = fname;
        super.lastName = lname;
        super.gender = gen;
        super.dependents = dep;
        super.annualSalary = annualSalary;
        super.benefit = benefit;
        while (true) {
            if (!validWage(wage_)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid wage : ");
                in3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                wage_ = in3.nextDouble();
            } else {
                this.wage = wage_;
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            if (!validHour(hours_)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid hours : ");
                hours_ = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
            } else {
                this.hours = hours_;
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            if (!validCategory(category_)) {
                System.out.print("Invalid category, please enter another category value: ");
                in4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                category_ = in4.next();
            } else {
                this.category = category_;
                break;
            }
        }
        annualSalary = wage * hours * 52;
        //numEmployees++;
    }

    private boolean validHour(double hour) {
        return (MIN_HOURS <= hour && hour <= MAX_HOURS);
    }

    private boolean validWage(double wage) {
        return (MIN_WAGE <= wage && wage <= MAX_WAGE);
    }

    private boolean validCategory(String category) {
        String[] categories = {"temp", "part time", "full time"};
        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++)
            if (category.equalsIgnoreCase(categories[i]))
                return true;
        return false;       
    }

    public double calculatePay() {
        return annualSalary / 52;
    }       

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(super.toString());
        sb.append("Wage: ").append(wage).append("\n");
        sb.append("Hours: ").append(hours).append("\n");
        sb.append("Category: ").append(category).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Benefit.Class**

```
public class Benefit {
    private String healthInsurance;
    private double lifeInsurance;
    private int vacationDays;



public Benefit() {
        healthInsurance = "Full";
        lifeInsurance = 100;
        vacationDays = 5;
    }

    public Benefit(String health, double life, int vacation) {
        setHealthInsurance(health);
        setLifeInsurance(life);
        setVacation(vacation);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Health Insurance: ").append(healthInsurance).append("\n");
        sb.append("Life Insurance: ").append(lifeInsurance).append("\n");
        sb.append("Vacation Days: ").append(vacationDays).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void setHealthInsurance(String healthInsurance) {
        this.healthInsurance = healthInsurance;
    }

    public String getHealthInsurance() {
        return healthInsurance;
    }

    public void setLifeInsurance(double lifeInsurance) {
        this.lifeInsurance = lifeInsurance;
    }

    public double getLifeInsurance() {
        return lifeInsurance;
    }

    public void setVacation(int vacation) {
        this.vacationDays = vacation;
    }

    public int getVacation() {
        return vacationDays;
    }

    public void displayBenefit() {
        this.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: `public <Gender> char getGender()` Is that generics with a type parameter called `Gender`? If so, why? It's never used. Why do you have a type parameter on your getGender() and setGender() methods?

Comment: @nrubin29  umm actually I'm not sure that was an error change that java made I didn't understand it but it made the red X's disappear

Comment: Just remove the `<Gender>` from those two methods.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)...

What you basically want is to use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, which can be used to prompt the use for input...

Yes, there are a few flavours, but lets keep it simply and look at [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object))

The JavaDocs tells us that...

> message - the Object to display
>   Returns:
> user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

So, from that we could use something like...

```
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
if (value != null) {
    System.out.println("Hello " + value);
} else {
    System.out.println("Hello no name");
}
```

Which displays...

[image: Dialog]

Now, if we take a look at your code, you could replace the use of `scan` with...

```
public static String getInput(String inputType) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the " + inputType + ": ");
    return input;
}
```

As an example...

Now, what I might recommend is creating a simple helper method which can be used to prompt the user in a single line of code, for example...

```
public class InputHelper {
    public static String promptUser(String prompt) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        return input;
    }
}
```

which might be used something like...

```
String value = InputHelper.promptUser("Please enter the hours worked");
hours_ = Double.parse(value);
```

And this is where it get's messy, as you will now need to valid the input of the user.

You could extend the idea of the `InputHelper` to do automatic conversions and re-prompt the user if the value was invalid...as an idea

Comment: +1, nice and well written answer.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Hopefully I covered the basics enough for the OP to try an attempt on their own :P

Comment: This is what Stack Overflow is for, for something instead of your attemp, I think oDesk and Elance are designed! :) To hire a _MadProgrammer_ :D

Comment: Yes Yes thank you this has help me even more thank u

Comment: @uknownothing I'm glad we could help, have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier than you think, if you try. Get used to reading the Java API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Even has examples.

> ```
>  String input;
>  JOptionPane jop=new JOptionPane();
>  input=jop.showInputDialog("Question i want to ask");
>
>  System.out.println(input);
> ```

Comment: From the SO help center: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Can you include an example in your answer?

Comment: I think this answer is welcome here because he has provided the example from the link. Still I would like to ask @MarGar to add a few details to the post :) It would help the OP and the future reader to understand what you tried to answer here. :)

Comment: oh man thank u for this has help me a lot